# Problems loading assembly dependencies dynamically at run-time

Tags: .net, reflection, assembly-resolution

let me try to explain my problem. I'm currently trying to develop a small "plugin-framework" written in .Net (mainly for experimenting a bit). So the idea is to have a main application to which "plugins" can be added by deploying dlls in a specific folder "plugins" of the main application.
Everything works fine, the plugins are instantiated properly, however now I'm facing a problem. 
I have deployed now a plugin "X" that uses additional 3rd-party plugins and so now I have the problem that these additional 3rd-party plugins required by "X" are not found at run-time. My idea is therefore now to add an additional directory "dependencies" where I also deploy all of the needed plugins.

So my first question:
How can I load the assemblies into the application domain (given that I know the path to them) s.t. they can be used by my application?

I tried to approach that by doing something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //find the path to the assembly and then load and return it by
    //return Assembly.Load("pathToDependencies/failedAssembly.dll");
}
```

The problem is that this event-handler now gets activated having the "Presentation.Zune.dll" in the args variable (I'm using a WPF app). It seems as if that assembly failed loading but the actual problem is another dll.

Can someone suggest me a better way to solve my problem? I hope that I was able to explain my situation sufficiently, otherwise just ask for further clarification.

Thanks,
Juri

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the probing path of the runtime so it can find the assemblies. Set the [probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) element in your apps config file.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="plugins;dependencies"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `AssemblyResolve` event happens when the framework tries to load an assembly, and fails.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)

What this means is that if it's giving you `Presentation.Zune.dll` in the args, that the framework can't find that assembly, and this is your chance to intercept it and do other things, like load it from a directory that the framework might not know about - eg your plugins\dependencies folder...

Off the top of my head, I'd try something like this:

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if( File.Exists(".\\Plugins\\"+args.Name) )  // it's a plugin
        return Assembly.Load(".\\Plugins\\"+args.Name);
    else if( File.Exists(".\\Plugins\\Dependencies\\"+args.Name) )  // it's a dependency OF a plugin
        return Assembly.Load(".\\Plugins\\Dependencies\\"+args.Name);
    else
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Is this correct?  I believe that AssemblyResolve is called only when the runtime fails to resolve an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

BTW: You can speed up loading assemblies considerably if you cache your assemblies that you already resolved in a Dictionary. If A depends on B, C and B depends on C and you load A, AssemblyResolve will be called twice for C, and loading the assembly only once is faster :)

(I am not sure if it is always the case that AssemblyResolve is called more than once, but I noticed it when debugging a project once. And it does not hurt to cache the assemblies...)