# How can I add a probingPath at runtime (and not through app.config)?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I need to add an assembly probing path **at runtime**, not through the  element in app.config. Is there a way to do this?

The reason is so that my XOML-only workflow that resides in it's own folder can know where to find it's related DLLs (i.e. containing custom Activities). Currently I am getting fusion errors because the CLR is probing the wrong paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to do is something like what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592681/problems-loading-assembly-dependencies-dynamically-at-run-time) is about. Resolving assemblies that is not found by probing is done by hooking up with [the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).

Whether you can use this approach to load activity assemblies requested by your workflow depends on whether a central event handler can figure out where to look for those assemblies given the workflow it tries to load.